# Calculating the probability of at least 2 duplicates in a world with 400 tiles and 50 objects? Java

Tags: java, probability, birthday-paradox

First of all I want to let you know that I have been searching for some days now for an answer or something that could perhaps help me out a bit but I couldn't find anything so I am asking here.

I have in my Java code:

An arraylist of 50 objects.
Random X and Y elements put into each object in the arraylist.
Method checking if there are duplicates.

So based on the amount of duplicates(Not sure about this part but other people I know seem to do it like this) I need to calculate the probability of at least 2 objects having the same coordinates in a world of 400 tiles/choices (20x20). The world of 400 tiles does not exist yet in my code but I have to calculate it by thinking of that.

The probability should be something like 0.95xx in the end of having at least a duplicate.

So I know I have to calculate the probability of getting NO duplicates and do: (1 - P(NoDupes)). But how do I calculate P(NoDupes)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the coordinates of objects determined?

Comment: `So based on the amount of duplicates I need to calculate the probability of at least 2 objects having the same coordinates in a world of 400 tiles (20x20).` If you're basing this on the number of duplicates then `probability = numberOfDuplicates >= 1 ? 1 : 0;` because you've already found them..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack This might be useful. I don't fully understand the question though

Comment: the world of 400 tiles isnt implemented in the code yet, but based on 400 tiles I need to calculate. The coordinates are X,Y generated randomly by the Random class. But the coordinates don't matter for the calculation

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this a few times I think what you're asking is:

Given a 20x20 grid, what is the probability that there will be at least one collision when inserting 50 random points?

If this is indeed what you are asking then a simple way of coming up with an answer is by the following logic:

The first object cannot collide with anything since it is the first. So the chance of no collision here is 400/400 = 1.
The second object can only collide with the first object. So the chance of no collision is 399/400.
The third object can collide with the first or the second. So the chance here is 398/400.
...
The nth object can collide with any of the previous n-1 objects. So the chance here is (400-(n-1))/400 (or if n is greater than 400 the chance is just 0).

The chance of no collision for n objects is then just the product (400/400)(399/400)...((400-(n-1))/400)
The chance of at least one collision is then as you correctly said 1 - P(No Collision).

Comment: I think this cleared some things up for me, I will have a look right now!

Comment: What if I generate some worlds with different amount of collisions, can I then calculate the Probability of getting at least 1 collision with the number of collisions found?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that. If you are generating points and checking for collisions that has nothing to do with the actual probability of collision (this probability is a constant `1 - (400/400)(399/400)...(351/400) = 1 - 0.0408 = 0.9592`)

Comment: If the assignment is to approximate this probability by generating the points a bunch of times and checking for collisions then the solution would be `number_of_runs_with_at_least_one_collision / total_number_of_runs`.

Comment: Basically what I saw in the code of other people was: They generate the world, show the amount of collisions. They then calculate the probability of at least 1 collision using the amount of collisions found. They also simulate the world one million times to get the chance...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Think of this problem as drawing elements from a set of 400 with replacement.  The 2-d coordinates are a distraction.

Then compute  1 - P(NO DUPES) - P(1 DUPE) - P(2 DUPES)

Comment: Yes but how do I compute the probability of no dupes?

Comment: First note that: 400^50 total possible arraylists.  Now count selections without replacement and consider the ratio

Comment: Dont think Ill figure it out this way ;P Sorry just a second year IT student and it has been a long time since I had probability.. I just can't figure how to get P(No dupes)

Comment: look into the definition of 400 choose 50.  Then divide it by 400^50

Comment: @user1842140 Why do you need to implement it in java? Is it always 50 objects and 400 tiles? If so, you can do the calculation by hand and hardcode the value in